# stair-stepping when using a pty (through ssh) and piping to more

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ssh, pty

This is a problem that has been driving me nuts, and I can't figure out a solution. My program:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
ssh -t myuser@anotherhost "cat ~/severalLineFile"
```

and `~/severalLineFile` on `anotherhost` looks like:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

When I run my program by itself, the output to my terminal looks as expected. However, when resize my terminal such that it is only 5 rows, and pipe my program to less, it looks like:

```
line1
     line2
          line3
               line4
                    :
```

and when pressing space bar at that point, it prints out `line5` and `line6` (and any additional lines) like:

```
line5
line6
```

now i understand that this is a result of running the ssh in a pseudo-terminal, and that this stair-stepping happens because of carriage returns being included in the newline. I've tried using `stty ocrnl` but this doesn't do what I want, namely for that initial print of less to behave like everything after I press spacebar.

Btw I need to run `ssh` in `-t` mode because I'd like all `ctrl+C` keyboard interrupts to make their way though to the remote process. If there's a solution on this side of things, i'm all ears. I am on Linux Server 6.1, terminal is through Mac OS 10.6.8

I've also tried to replace the `\r\n` that the pseudo-terminal produces with `\n`, but this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove extra carriage return characters you have to use `stty -onlcr`, not `stty onlcr` (see: [Extra Carriage Return on Each Printed Line](http://www.censoft.com/support/kb/?p=528)).

What happens if you first pipe the output of the `ssh` command to `cat -v` and then to `less`?

```
ssh -t localhost "stty -echo -onlcr; cat testfile.txt; stty echo onlcr" | cat -v | less -U
```

If you want your `ctrl+C` keyboard interrupts to propagate through to the remote process, you may try an "EOF to SIGHUP" converter via a named pipe (see: [ssh command unexpectedly continues on other system after ssh terminates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74883); to kill the entire remote shell use: `kill -HUP -- -$$`).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is EOL markers; MacOS uses CR (`\r` aka `\x0d`) characters, Linux uses LF (`\n` aka `\x0a`). Due to supporting terminal drawing characters like the CR, ssh is interpreting them as characters that move the cursor around the screen instead of EOL markers. Try this:

```
ssh -t myuser@anotherhost "sed -e 's,\\r,\\n,' ~/severalLineFile"
```

OR

```
ssh -t myuser@anotherhost "tr '\\r' '\\n' < ~/severalLineFile"
```

If that doesn't work you can use `scp` to copy the file to the terminal:

```
scp myuser@anotherhost:severalLineFile /dev/stdout
```

Comment: MacOS hasn't used CR for line endings since MacOS 9. That's 10 years ago. I suspect the problem has more to do with terminal emulation and `less` not dealing with the window size in the expected way.

Comment: added the MacOS version to the above (10.6.8), but feel that it's something to do with the terminal emulation - @amphetamachine, thx but these don't solve the problem - I've tried every EOL replacement variation and nothing seems to work. Btw it's not just less that has this problem, exact same goes for piping it to more. I do like the /dev/stdout angle, but I'm not actually `cat`ing a file on a remote machine, rather running a process

Comment: to be clear, the purpose of resizing my terminal window to be 5 lines is that for my 6-line example, `less` has to paginate at that point (since i have 6 lines), and the terminal only starts displaying correctly after pressing the spacebar (i.e. page #2)

Comment: `more` is just a hardlink to `less` on recent versions of Mac OS X, maybe as long ago as 10.4.

Comment: ok cool thx, I'm actually logged in through a linux box, where I'm running less/more